# Local CocoaPods interfering with other pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm writing a Swift Framework and a Swift iOS Application and I'm trying to use Cocoapods to add my framework into my app and other sdks as well.

Here is my podspec for my swift framework

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "InfraCocoa"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of InfraCocoa."
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author             = { "" => "" }
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = "7.0 "
  s.source_files  = "Classes", "Classes/**/*.{swift,h,m}"
end
```

My pod podfile for my iOS app

```
target 'CocoaProjectTest' do

pod 'InfraCocoa', :path => '~/Documents/workspaces/CocoaPodsTesting/Infra/InfraCocoa'
pod 'CrashlyticsFramework', '2.2.5.2'
pod 'GoogleTagManager', '3.09'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.0.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.23.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.5.1'

end
```

Now at first if I run the 'pod install' or 'pod update' everything works fine. The problem is when I try to build in Xcode(6.1.1). I get a compile error saying stuff like this
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:

```
  -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl closeDatabase] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)


 (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_close)
```

After a few google searchs I found it is because my GoogleTagManager is missing the libraries 'libz.dylib' and 'libsqllite3.dylib' in it's 'Link Binary With Libraries'. I can manually add them and it will compile although this is not ideal.

I decided to test without the following line in my podfile and it compiles

```
pod 'InfraCocoa', :path => '~/Documents/workspaces/CocoaPodsTesting/Infra/InfraCocoa'
```

I figured it was probably because of a conflict in library version but this InfraCocoa framework is completely clean and empty (did a File-> New-> Project -> CocoaTouch Framework).

Any ideas? (the app project too is empty and clean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could have overridden the GoogleTagManager.podspec in your PodFile and simply add the missing libraries in your modified version of the file.

something like:

```
pod 'GoogleTagManager', :podspec => './GoogleTagManager.podspec.json'
```

and in the podspec:

```
"libraries": ["GoogleAnalyticsServices", "sqlite3", "z"],
```

Seems to be working with cocoapods 0.36.rc.1